# Compare items in list if tuples Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

If have this list of tuples:

```
l1 = [('aa', 1),('de', 1),('ac', 3),('ab', 2),('de', 2),('bc', 4)]
```

I want to loop over it, and check if the second item in each tuple is the same as another second item in a tuple in this list. If it is, I want to put this tuple in a new list of tuples.

So from this list of tuples I would expect for my new list of tuples:

```
l2 = [('aa', 1), ('de', 1), ('ab', 2),('de', 2)]
```

Because the one's and the two's match. Right now if have this:

```
l2 = []
for i in range(len(l1)):
    if l1[i][1] in l1[:][0]:
        l2.append(l1[i])
```

However, this only gives me:

```
l2 = [('aa', 1), ('de', 1)]
```

I'm pretty sure I'm not indexing the list of tuples right. The solution is probably pretty simple, but I'm just not getting there.

Comment: `l1[:][0]` only checks the first element of the list, and no others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need two passes: one to count how many times the second element exists, and another to then build the new list based on those counts:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(id_ for s, id_ in l1)
l2 = [(s, id_) for s, id_ in l1 if counts[id_] > 1]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l1 = [('aa', 1),('de', 1),('ac', 3),('ab', 2),('de', 2),('bc', 4)]
>>> counts = Counter(id_ for s, id_ in l1)
>>> [(s, id_) for s, id_ in l1 if counts[id_] > 1]
[('aa', 1), ('de', 1), ('ab', 2), ('de', 2)]
```

Your code goes wrong with `l1[:][0]`; `l1[:]` just creates a *shallow copy* of the list, then takes the first element from that list. Even if it worked, your approach would have to check *every other element in your list* for every tuple you consider, which is really inefficient (the code would take N**2 steps for a list of N tuples).